# Installing Rasterio and GDAL API in a virtuallenv in Windows 10

Tags: python, gdal, installation, rasterio, windows-10

Following rasterio installation guidelines ([rasterio.readthedocs.io](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html)) 
I downloaded the relevant wheel files from Cristoph's list ([link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs))
and installed them successfully on my Windows 10 system. Yet I am failing to install them in my virtualenv I created using Pycharm. For sanity check, I tested I was able to install numpy with pip in the virtualenv.

```
$ pip install -U pip
$ pip install GDAL-1.11.2-cp27-none-win32.whl
$ pip install rasterio-0.24.0-cp27-none-win32.whl
```

Unfrutently the red error message is not very informative. I have checked the bases I know such as, the system, and python are 64, pip is linked to python 3.8. This is all I can think of. Below you can see a few of my steps.

[image]

**Update:**
It seems that setting up the virtual environment manual from the Command Prompt and **not Pycharm** paved the way to a successful GDFAL and Rasteiro installation.

1. Download virtualenv: C:\Users\t>pip install --user virtualenv
2. Create virtualenv: C:\Users\t\Downloads>python -m venv
3. Activate: C:\Users\t\Downloads>test_virtual_env_i\env\Scripts\activate

Then installing the respective downloaded GDAL wheel worked out of the box:

1. (env) C:\Users\t\Downloads>pip install GDAL-3.0.2-cp38-cp38-
   win_amd64.whl
2. (env) C:\Users\esaiet\Downloads>pip install rasterio-1.1.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl

Before I can conclude the issue is resolved, the qyestion is what is the difference between the my virtualenv installation and Pycharm.

Comment: try installing gdal 2.4 with rasterio 1.0.24

Comment: 2.4.1 did not work, I will update in my post above.

Comment: It works for me.  Make sure you are installing the correct version of each, i.e if you're using Python 3.8 64bit don't use the GDAL wheel for Python 3.5  or Python 2 (you said you tried to install GDAL-2.4.1-**cp35**-cpm35m-win_amd64.whl and GDAL-1.11.2-**cp27**-none-win32.whl), you need GDAL-3.0.2-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl and rasterio-1.1.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl.

Comment: Yup, I have python 3.8 and tried installing GDAL rasterio‑1.1.1‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl. I tried GDAL 2.4.1 because you suggested it. cp27 was listed as the general instructions. Can you post your exact steps? How did you create the virtualenv, what python verisn did you use,everything?

Comment: After installing python, you may have to upgrade pip by `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` and then install gdal.whl again by `GDAL-1.11.2-cp27-none-win32.whl`. Make sure that python directory are defined in OS path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed these steps and it worked find for me.

- OS: Microsoft Windows x64

1. Install **python 3.5**
2. Add `x:\<python_directory>`, `x:\<python_directory>\Lib` and `x:\<python_directory>\Scripts` to system environment variable `PATH`.
3. Upgrade the **pip** by running code `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`
4. Install compatible version of **GDAL** by `python -m pip install GDAL-3.0.4-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl`
5. Install compatible version of **Rasterio** by `python -m pip install rasterio-1.1.2-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl`

Following images proves the result:

[image]

And when I ran the last command (number 5) following results were shown:

[image]