# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_gdal'

Tags: gdal, python-3, osgeo, windows-10, importerror

I am using Python 3.6 and still having this problem,, although I have tried to uninstall both numpy and GDAL and installed them again in the order numpy then GDAL

I am using Windows 10.

This was my code:

```py
import numpy
import PIL
import osgeo
from osgeo import gdal
import raster2xyz
from raster2xyz import Raster2xyz
from PIL import Image
```

and this is the error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Tutorials/19august.py", line 3, in import osgeo File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\osgeo_init_.py", line 32, in gdal = swig_import_helper() File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\osgeo_init.py", line 31, in swig_import_helper return importlib.import_module('gdal') File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib_init.py", line 126, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_gdal'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Arash Madadi](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/67659/arash-madadi) pointed out in his answer, you need Python 3.5 for this to work. As far as I know, there is no way around this, but please correct me, if you find a way.

After you installed Python 3.5 64bit (didn't test it for 32bit), follow these steps to run your snippet from above:

1. Setup a new and clean virtual environment for python 3.5 64bit (not strictly necessary, but it makes handling those libs easier, especially since we are going to install some outdated ones)
2. Install this wheel: *GDAL‑3.0.4‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl* from here [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal)
3. Install this wheel: *rasterio‑1.0.18‑cp34‑cp34m‑win_amd64.whl* from here [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#rasterio](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#rasterio)
4. Install this wheel: *llvmlite‑0.31.0‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl* from here [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#llvmlite](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#llvmlite)
5. Install this wheel: *numpy‑1.16.6+mkl‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl* from here [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)
6. Install *raster2xyz* with: `pip install raster2xyz`
7. Install *raster2points* with: `pip install raster2points==0.1.8` (latest version uses `numba 0.49.1` which is not available for python 3.5)

Note, that you'll have to change your import of Raster2xyz to `from raster2xyz.raster2xyz import Raster2xyz`

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/343835/installing-rasterio-and-gdal-api-in-a-virtuallenv-in-windows-10/371720#371720). I explained how someone can install `gdal 3.0.4` by `Python 3.5` on `microsoft windows machine`.

You can download `GDAL-3.0.4-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl` file via [this link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal). Make sure you download appropriate version which is compatible with your windows (x64/86) and python.

Comment: Thank you, i will try

Comment: I am afraid this did not work for me, and i do not know why, i could not upgrade pip for python, as it gave me this error:  python -m pip install --upgrade pip
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax, and although i downloaded both gdal and rasterio, still can not be imported