# GDAL doesn't recognize gdal.ViewshedGenerate (Python API)

Tags: python, gdal, viewshed

GDAL has a function called `gdal_viewshed`. I checked on the GDAL's Python API to see if there is a function I can call in a Python script and I found `gdal.ViewshedGenerate`.

https://gdal.org/python/index.html

However, when I run a script calling this function I get the following message:

```
AttributeError: module 'osgeo.gdal' has no attribute 'ViewshedGenerate'
```

I tried with the latest GDAL version (3.0.2) and version 2.3.3 and I always get this message.

The problem is not the code but the fact that GDAL doesn't recognize this function. Does anybody know why I can't use this function although it is on the Python API documentation?

I couldn't even find any information about this function anywhere apart from the mentioned documentation.

Comment: GDAL 3.0.2 is not the latest.

Answer (score 1):

Have a closer look at https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_viewshed.html.

> New in version 3.1.0.

Comment: Thank you. Anaconda only let me update to version 3.0.2 so I supposed it was the latest version.

Answer (score -1):

I explained how to install GDAL successfully on MS Windows. Follow [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/343835/installing-rasterio-and-gdal-api-in-a-virtuallenv-in-windows-10/371720#371720) on GIS Stackchange to install GDAL easily on your machine.

Comment: Thanks. I installed GDAL using Anaconda on Windows and I haven't had any problem using its functions. The only problem I had is when I tried to call gdal.ViewshedGenerate.